# Basic minesweeper. Bomb counter function not working

Tags: c++, numbers, srand, tracker

I've been working on some code for a basic minesweeper program and at this point I'm complacently lost. The numbers around the bombs wont generate properly and there doesn't even seem to be a pattern to whats going wrong. I need help with finding a way to fix this issue without having to re-wright my enter program. my teacher cant figure out a way to help me and suggests that I use what i have to make a luck based game sense its due Tuesday. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int GameBoard [9] [9] = { };
int BombTracker [20] = { };
srand(time(0));
for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++ ) //generates 10 bombs
{
    int TX;
    int TY;
    int MX = rand() % 8;
    int MY = rand() % 8;

    for ( TY = 1, TX = 0; TY <= 19; TX+=2, TY+=2)//cycle through array 
    {
        if (MY == BombTracker [TY] && MX == BombTracker [TX])//Regenerate and restart count if found true
            {
              MX = rand() % 8;
              MY = rand() % 8;
                TY = -1;
                TX = -2;
            }
    }
    GameBoard [MX] [MY] = 9;
if (MY == 0 && MX == 0) //(0,0)
    {
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //5: my,mx+1
        MY = MY + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //7: my+1,mx+1
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //6: my+1,mx
    }
if (MY == 0 && MX == 8) //(8,0)
    {
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //1: my,mx-1
        MY = MY -1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //2: my-1,mx-1
        MY = MY + 2;
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //6: my+1,mx
    }
if (MY == 8 && MX == 0) //(0,8)
    {
        MY = MY - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //3: my-1,mx
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //4: my-1,mx+1
        MY = MY + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //5: my,mx+1
    }
if (MY == 8 && MX == 8) //(8,8)
    {
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //1: my,mx-1
        MY = MY -1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //2: my-1,mx-1
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //3: my-1,mx
    }
if ((MX >= 1 && MX < 8) && (MY > 7)) //  bottom row
    {
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //1: my,mx-1
        MY = MY -1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //2: my-1,mx-1
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //3: my-1,mx
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //4: my-1,mx+1
        MY = MY + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //5: my,mx+1
    }
if ((MX >= 1 && MX < 8) && (MY < 1)) // top row
    {
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //1: my,mx-1
        MX = MX + 2;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //5: my,mx+1
        MY = MY + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //7: my+1,mx+1
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //6: my+1,mx
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //8: my+1,mx-1
    }
if ((MX > 7) && (MY >= 1 &&MY < 8)) // right column
    {
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //1: my,mx-1
        MY = MY -1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //2: my-1,mx-1
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //3: my-1,mx
        MY = MY + 2;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //6: my+1,mx
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //8: my+1,mx-1
    }
if ((MX > 7) && (MY >= 1 &&MY < 8)) // left column
    {
        MY = MY - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //3: my-1,mx
        MX = MX + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //4: my-1,mx+1
        MY = MY + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //5: my,mx+1
        MY = MY + 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //7: my+1,mx+1
        MX = MX - 1;
        GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //6: my+1,mx
    }
if ((MX >= 1 && MX < 8)&&(MY >= 1 && MY < 8)) // middle of the board
{
    MX = MX - 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //1: my,mx-1
    MY = MY -1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //2: my-1,mx-1
    MX = MX + 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //3: my-1,mx
    MX = MX + 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //4: my-1,mx+1
    MY = MY + 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //5: my,mx+1
    MY = MY + 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //7: my+1,mx+1
    MX = MX - 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //6: my+1,mx
    MX = MX - 1;
    GameBoard [MY] [MX] = GameBoard [MY] [MX] + 1; //8: my+1,mx-1
}
}
    int width = 9;
    int height = 9;
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    {
        cout <<GameBoard[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using a debugger? What did you learn?

Comment: `for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++)` generates 11 bombs.

Comment: You set your bomb's position with `GameBoard [MX] [MY] = 9;` but you increment the counters with `GameBoard [MY] [MX]` Notice `MX` and `MY` are inverted.

Comment: the only thing that I found in debugger appeared only on my mac in xcode (I've been writing this mostly on a school windows computer in codeblocks) and was with the srand and doesn't relay have anything to do with the counting for the numbers.

Comment: You should add more comments.  Comments after the variables to explain how you intend to use them.  Comments for each block to explain what exactly you are trying to do in that block.  This could help find logical errors by itself, and other people reading your code will have an easier time finding any coding errors if they have the English explanation to compare them to.

Comment: There is also a problem with your logic regarding avoiding placing bombs where bombs are already present. If you find that a bomb is already present, you pick a new coordinate but do not check with previous bombs' position. You don't even need `BombTracker`, just check if `GameBoard` is 9 or more at the prospective position.

Comment: It seems to be somewhat working now but not internally. not sure how to post a photo of it.

Comment: @nina don't! Copy/Paste the console output into your [edit]ed answer.

Comment: By the way, is it intentional not to generate bombs on the last row and column? `rand()%8` gives an integer in [0;7].

Comment: No, just changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Source code you have posted here is hard to follow, has a lot of magic numbers. It's a maintenance nightmare to support such code.

Try to give your variables good names, that describe the entity that variable
represents.

Try to encapsulate each small task within its own routine.

For example logic for determining adjacent cells for a target cell is pretty straightforward and can be implemented by using Compass metaphor. So here we have eight Directions - one for each cardinal direction

[image]

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

enum Compass
{
  North,
  NorthEast,
  East,
  SouthEast,
  South,
  SouthWest,
  West,
  NorthWest
};
```

Then define enumeration for each edge of minefield board, Direction class and type for indexing board cells.

```
enum BoardEdge
{
  Inside,
  Top,
  TopRight,
  Right,
  BottomRight,
  Bottom,
  BottomLeft,
  Left,
  TopLeft
};

struct CellIndex2D;

using IndexType = std::size_t;
using CellIndex2DList = std::vector<CellIndex2D>;
using CellIndex1D = std::size_t;

struct CellIndex2D
{
  IndexType X;
  IndexType Y;
};

struct Direction
{
  explicit Direction(CellIndex2D targetCell) noexcept
    :cell_(targetCell) {}

  template <Compass C>
  CellIndex2D To() const;

private:
  CellIndex2D cell_;
};
```

Now we have all bits and pieces to determine index of each target cell adjacent cells. Following our Compass metaphor X coordinate for North cell is equals to target cell X coordinate and Y coordinate is less by one from target one:

```
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<North>() const
{
  return{ cell_.X, (cell_.Y - 1) };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<NorthEast>() const
{
  return{ (cell_.X + 1), (cell_.Y - 1) };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<East>() const
{
  return{ (cell_.X + 1), cell_.Y };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<SouthEast>() const
{
  return{ (cell_.X + 1), (cell_.Y + 1) };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<South>() const
{
  return{ cell_.X, (cell_.Y + 1) };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<SouthWest>() const
{
  return{ (cell_.X - 1), (cell_.Y + 1) };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<West>() const
{
  return{ (cell_.X - 1), cell_.Y };
}
template <>
inline CellIndex2D Direction::To<NorthWest>() const
{
  return{ (cell_.X - 1), (cell_.Y - 1) };
}
```

Now lets describe adjacent cells for each edge type of the board, for example cell in top left corner has only three adjacent cells:

```
template <BoardEdge BE = Inside>
struct AdjacentCells
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<North>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<East>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<South>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthWest>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<West>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthWest>())
    };
  }
};

template <>
struct AdjacentCells<Top>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<East>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<South>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthWest>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<West>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<TopRight>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<South>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthWest>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<West>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<Right>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<North>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<South>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthWest>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<West>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthWest>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<BottomRight>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<North>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<West>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthWest>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<Bottom>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<North>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<East>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<West>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthWest>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<BottomLeft>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<North>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<East>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<Left>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<North>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<NorthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<East>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<South>())
    };
  }
};
template <>
struct AdjacentCells<TopLeft>
{
  static CellIndex2DList Get(CellIndex2D targetCell)
  {
    Direction direction{ targetCell };

    return CellIndex2DList{
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<East>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<SouthEast>()),
      CellIndex2D(direction.To<South>())
    };
  }
};
```

And we are ready to define routine that actually give us a list of adjacent cell indices for target cell:

```
CellIndex2DList GetAdjacentCellIndices(CellIndex2D targetCell, std::size_t mfWidth, std::size_t mfHeight)
{
  //TODO: check that targetCell is within minefield bounds

  //Check if cell lies on one of the board edges (left, right, top, bottom)
  bool le = targetCell.X == 0;
  bool re = (targetCell.X + 1) == mfWidth;
  bool te = targetCell.Y == 0;
  bool be = (targetCell.Y + 1) == mfHeight;

  bool inc = !te && !be; //cell is between top and bottom edges
  bool inr = !le && !re; //cell is between left and right edges

  //cell is inside board
  if (inc && inr)
    return AdjacentCells<Inside>::Get(targetCell);

  //left edge cell
  if (le && inc)
    return AdjacentCells<Left>::Get(targetCell);
  //right edge cell
  if (re && inc)
    return AdjacentCells<Right>::Get(targetCell);
  //top edge cell
  if (te && inr)
    return AdjacentCells<Top>::Get(targetCell);
  //bottom edge cell
  if (be && inr)
    return AdjacentCells<Bottom>::Get(targetCell);

  //topleft corner cell
  if (te && le)
    return AdjacentCells<TopLeft>::Get(targetCell);
  //bottomleft corner cell
  if (be && le)
    return AdjacentCells<BottomLeft>::Get(targetCell);
  //topright corner cell
  if (te && re)
    return AdjacentCells<TopRight>::Get(targetCell);
  //bottomright corner cell
  if (be && re)
    return AdjacentCells<BottomRight>::Get(targetCell);

  return{};
}
```

Lets create Minefield class, Generate function will do all hard work for creating minefield. We just loop while all mines not placed. On each iteration we generate random index within board, if there is no mine already exist, put it by this index and increase weight for all neighboring cells:

```
class MineField
{
public:
  MineField(std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
      :
  width_{ width },
  height_{ height },
  cells_{ width *height }
  {  }

  void Generate(std::size_t mineCount)
  {
    using unsigned_distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>;

    std::random_device    rand;
    std::mt19937          engine(rand());

    unsigned_distribution xDist(0u, width_ - 1);
    unsigned_distribution yDist(0u, height_ - 1);

    std::uint16_t mc = 0;
    while (mc != mineCount)
    {
      CellIndex2D cellIndex{ xDist(engine), yDist(engine) };
      CellIndex1D index = convertIndex2DTo1D(cellIndex);

      if (hasMine(index))
        continue;

      putMine(index);

      //Increase weight for all adjacent squares around mine
      auto&& adjacentCellsList = GetAdjacentCellIndices(cellIndex, width_, height_);
      for (auto adjIndex : adjacentCellsList)
        increaseCellWeightByOne(convertIndex2DTo1D(adjIndex));

      ++mc;
    }
  }

  void Print() const
  {
    std::stringstream out{};

    std::size_t rowCellsCount = 0;
    for (auto&& cell : cells_)
    {
      if (cell.HasMine)
        out << "* ";
      else
        out << cell.Weight << " ";

      rowCellsCount++;
      if (rowCellsCount == width_)
      {
        out << '\n';
        rowCellsCount = 0;
      }
    }

    std::cout << out.str();
  }

private:
  struct Cell
  {
    std::size_t Weight;
    bool        HasMine;
  };

  bool hasMine(CellIndex1D cellIndex) const
  {
    return cells_[cellIndex].HasMine;
  }

  void putMine(CellIndex1D cellIndex)
  {
    cells_[cellIndex].HasMine = true;
  }

  void increaseCellWeightByOne(CellIndex1D cellIndex)
  {
    cells_[cellIndex].Weight = cells_[cellIndex].Weight + 1;
  }

  CellIndex1D convertIndex2DTo1D(CellIndex2D targetCell) const
  {
    return{ (targetCell.X + targetCell.Y * width_) };
  }

private:
  std::vector<Cell> cells_;
  std::size_t       width_;
  std::size_t       height_;
};
```

Actually main application by itself. You can define any minefield size and mine count here:

```
int main()
{
  const std::size_t MfWidth = 9;
  const std::size_t MfHeight = 9;
  const std::size_t MineCount = 10;

  MineField mf{ MfWidth,MfHeight };

  mf.Generate(MineCount);
  mf.Print();

  return 0;
}
```

Output (mines are marked with stars):

```
2 * 2 1 3 * 2 0 0
2 * 2 1 * * 2 0 0
1 1 1 1 2 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 * 2
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 *
1 1 0 1 * 2 1 2 1
* 1 0 1 1 2 * 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

This code also not perfect and can be improved much by refactoring but on my opinion it is much more readable and can be easily debugged and tested.